# horizontal line; y axis as factor: ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I have a factor for my y variable and try to use `geom_hline` in `facet_grid` I get an error:

```
p <- qplot(mpg, factor(sample(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), nrow(mtcars), T)), data=mtcars, facets = vs ~ am)

hline.data <- data.frame(z = factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d")), vs = c(0,0,1,1), am = c(0,1,0,1))
p + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = z), hline.data)

## > p + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = z), hline.data)
## Error in x - from[1] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Why do I get the error and how can I fix it?

PS I can fix it by turning it to numeric as in:

```
hline.data <- data.frame(z = factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d")), vs = c(0,0,1,1), am = c(0,1,0,1))

qplot(mpg, as.numeric(factor(sample(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), nrow(mtcars), T))), data=mtcars, facets = vs ~ am) + 
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = as.numeric(z)), hline.data)
```

But I lose the desired factor labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>The</strike> A fix is to add a numeric version of `z`, not to convert it

```
hline.data <- data.frame(z = factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d")), vs = c(0,0,1,1), 
                         am = c(0,1,0,1))

## add numeric version of `z` as a new variable 
hline.data <- transform(hline.data, z0 = as.numeric(z))

p <- qplot(mpg, factor(sample(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), nrow(mtcars), T)), 
           data=mtcars, facets = vs ~ am)
p + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = z0), hline.data)
```

Producing

[image]

Comment: This works but feels like a hack.  Is this a bug in ggplot2 or perhaps something to be requested on its GitHub site?

Comment: @TylerRinker Hard to tell if it is a bug as the documentation doesn't say what `yintercept` accepts. There is no reasonable coordinate system in which a character factor makes sense. The y-axis is scaled numerically even though it is labelled with characters.

Comment: True but in a way this is similar to how a dotplot behaves.  I would expect this behavior to be extended here.  I put this through as a follow up on ggplot mailing list.